# How to Assign value with ng-change in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have simple drop-down bind with angular model

```
<select ui-select2="{allowClear:true}" ng-model="product.Id" ng-change="{value = product.Id == 0}" data-placeholder="Select Warranty">
      <option></option>
      <option ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product.Id}}">{{product.Code}}</option>
</select>
```

How i can assign value depending on some condition in ng-change?

Comment: I find it confusing that you are binding the selected option to a field "product.Id" since "product" seems to be valid only whitin ng-repeat. I'd rather use another name just as "selectedOptionId" or something like that. Makes the example easier to understand.

Answer (score 31):

Your selected value is defined as `ng-model`. On `ng-change` you can call a method from the controller and provide the "selected" `ng-model` to this method.

Here is an example:

```
<select                                               
        ng-model="product.Id"
        ng-options="filter as filter.name for filter in groupList"
        ng-change="changeItem(product.Id)"
         ></select>
```

*Controller*

```
$scope.changeItem = function(iem){

}
```

As a side note, I would use `ng-options` instead of `<option ng-repeat.....`

Comment: I think you don't need to pass the new value to the function since the value is also accessible via the changed model.

Comment: @lex82 If you have [a,b,c,d] in options and you selected 'b', the `product.Id` is going to be 'b' and this value is argument to `changeItem`.

Comment: Yeah, true, but since it is bounded to 'product.Id' you don't need to pass it as argument, because you can reach it in the function from the Controller's scope

Comment: @MartinSolev sure you can, but this way makes code clear and from HTML you can see what goes to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to the scope that checks the condition and assigns the value if it is true. Simply call this function from ng-change.