# Generic way to access to the input value in ngChange directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to execute some complex validation on fields of a form, where fields validation are bound together or rely on database information, so I don't want to test everything in the HTML. For the moment, I have this:

```
<select ng-options="i as i for i in parameters[offerType].SomeKey"
        ng-model="itemSelected.aQuiteLongProperty[offerType].SomeKey.parameterValue"
        ng-change="validateSomeKey(itemSelected.aQuiteLongProperty[offerType].SomeKey.parameterValue)">
</select>

---
$scope.validateSomeKey = function (val) {
     // check if the data is consistent 
};
```

As you can see, the `ng-model` is a little verbose so I would like to avoid the duplication in the `ng-change` directive. Is there a way to access to the `select`/`input` new value (option selected or the data entered), not like in [How to Assign value with ng-change in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089411/how-to-assign-value-with-ng-change-in-angular-js), but in a generic way?

I would like to have something like:

```
<select ng-options="i as i for i in parameters[offerType].SomeKey"
        ng-model="itemSelected.aQuiteLongProperty[offerType].SomeKey.parameterValue"
        ng-change="validateSomeKey($this.value)">
</select>
```

I tried to check in the `this` object, I did not found the data I wanted...

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient to set up a watcher in this case?

Comment: @Sprottenwels I thought about it also (since it gives the previous and new values) but I'm afraid to loose readability: some fields will have data validation and some not. By reading the HTML file, I want to know which fields have a validation function behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup><sub>This answer is just to mark the question as answered, even though no answer I would have expected seems possible. If someone (in a future version of Angular for example) finds an answer to the original problem, I will accept it :)</sub></sup>

I finally refactor my code, since my validators become more complex:

```
<select ng-options="i as i for i in parameters[offerType].SomeKey"
        ng-model="itemSelected.aQuiteLongProperty[offerType].SomeKey.parameterValue"
        ng-change="validate('SomeKey', itemSelected)">
</select>
```

and I have some layers at the end (since I will have around 100 validators, I came up with a flexible structure...), where I get my validators, for example:

```
validateSomeKey: function (key, $scope, item) {
     // offerType = item.some.propertyOffer.value
     // and access through item.aQuiteLongProperty[offerType][key].parameterValue
},
```

I still need to write again the full variable "path", but I can access to other parameters too (which is my need now).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the selected value in `ngChange`, it can be accessed inside the controller/directive using `scope`:

```
$scope.validateSomeKey = function(){
    /* do something with 
    $scope.itemSelected.aQuiteLongProperty[offerType].SomeKey.parameterValue */
}
```

Or you can use `ngInit`

```
<select 
ng-init="selectedValue = model.aVeryLongParentProperty.aVeryLongChildProperty" 
ng-model="selectedValue" 
ng-options="i.name for i in items" ng-change="changed(selectedValue)">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9s4A/)

Comment: I know this is also a way, but I really would like to avoid the duplication. I love the "DRY" principle :-)

Comment: There is no duplication as `ngModel` and the corresponding object defined on `scope` both point to one single object.

Comment: I mean duplication in the code. If some day aQuiteLongProperty becomes aShorterProperty, it would need to make changes in both JS and HTML file. Plus there is more risk of errors, cf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code#Problems_associated_with_duplicate_code

Comment: Another approach would be passing the event: `ng-change=someMethod($event)` that would give you access to the target element in the method and then you can use the element to get its value. Looks like a hack to me though.